# Set System Variable in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, 15.04, tcp-ip

I install Multipath TCP kernel and try to make it work. I don't know how to set the system variable as explained in http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureMPTCP.

Using Ubuntu 15.04, for the command (+sudo)  I get

```
sysctl -w net.mptcp.[name of the variable]=[value]

variable := net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager i.e. mptcp_path_manager

sysctl: setting key "net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager": No such file or directory
net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager = ndiffport
```

Please help. This is an assignment problem and I am badly stuck in trying to configure this.

Comment: I'm confused by your formatting here: what *exactly* are you typing, and what *exactly* is the response from the system?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual you provided you can set mptcp_enabled, mptcp_checksum, mptcp_syn_retries, mptcp_path_manager, mtcp_scheduler.

You can write commands:

```
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled=1
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_checksum=1
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_syn_retries=3
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager=default
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_mtcp_scheduler=default
```

These are just examples. You can set other values. These values are set for the running kernel and when you reboot they will be forgotten. If you want the system to rememeber these settings you have to put them in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` like this:

```
net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled=1
net.mptcp.mptcp_checksum=1
net.mptcp.mptcp_syn_retries=3
net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager=default
net.mptcp.mptcp_mtcp_scheduler=default
```

Again you set the values you want.

If you cannot set these parameters, I would say you don't have the support compiled into kernel.